# JavaScript: request to AWS RDS database to get online status

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'd like to get the status of my AWS RDS database instance through JavaScript, similarly to a normal http request to a website, however, in this case SQL's  listening port 1433, is this possible?

i.e

```
var http = new HttpClientRequest("http://xxx.xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433")
http.execute()
var response = http.response
if( response.code != 200 )
  throw "Request " + response.message
```

do I need node.js instead for that?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the database you're using, most likely it doesn't support HTTP. If you need to check its health, just try to connect to it via DB's own protocol.